# Can I build a hive table of millions of JSON blob documents

Tags: xml, json, azure, hadoop, hive

I am trying to get my head around big data in Windows Azure.

As a learning project I want to use the UK Companies House data as a test data source.  This gives me around 3.5 million records of company data and looks like this:
http://data.companieshouse.gov.uk/doc/company/02050399

As you can see the data is presented in multiple formats and for not other reason I'd like to use JSON (but happy to use XML or any other format if there are benefits)

Obviously, I don't want to query companies house direct and I might like to compliment this data with other data, such as tweets, for a big company search tool.

So, I tried with Storage Tables but found this didn't work as I wanted to do free text search over all properties, not just the Partition and Row keys.

Now I am thinking, could / should I store each company record as a blob in Azure blob storage as individual JSON files, then create a Hive table across all those millions of JSON documents.

Let's also pretend I might want to extend the JSON documents in the future with other "intelligence" relating to the companies, so each could get quite large.

1. Can I create a table on this scale using all these JSON docs as a source
2. Is there a better way to do it?

I welcome thoughts, comments and suggestions on alternative approaches to this problem.

Regards

Comment: Or, with this volume of data, would I be better sticking to SQL server?

Comment: As is, this question may be too broad for Stack Overflow. I suggest you slice the problem into more fundamental question which may be asked and answered with code examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hive is unlikely to give you an advantage over SQL server in this case. The data is simply too small.

So unless you really want to learn about HDInsight or Hive, I would go for the MS-SQL database.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense. Maybe my "structured" core data should be in SQL and the compliment is with lots of tweets, etc in Storage Tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to do full-text search, I'd suggest you have a look on Lucene(.Net), as it is design specifically for full-text search.

You'll have to put your documents (json files) in Azure Blobs, so Lucene can index it. Additionally to that you can place some meta-data into SQL Server or Azure Tables (that depends on what you are trying to do) that point to the blob with the data.